# How to select an element from Span tag using xpath or css selector

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver, xpath-1.0

I'm trying to automate process of pinging a person on a messenger on selecting the messenger name(Nayan)

Please find the Html code

```
<div class="Presence__text">
<span class="Presence__nameText">Nayan<span class="Presence__contactFlagIndicator"></span>
```

as text element present inside the span tag is unique (Nayan), i want to select based on that text element.

Problem statement :Unable to select an element using text present in span tag

I wanted to open the text of "Nayan" using xpath, can anyone help me solving this problem please.

Answer (score 1):

XPath can be used to locate elements based on their text content.
Accordingly to presented here HTML the following XPath can be used:

```
"//span[contains(text(),'Nayan')]"
```

Selenium command using this XPath in Java (you didn't mention the language you are using, but accordingly to your previous questions I see you are using Java) can be as following:

```java
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Nayan')]"));
```

In case "Nayan" text is unique it's always better to use `contains` rather to use `equals` method since web element may contain extra spaces.
I mean when possible `[contains(text(),'Nayan')]` is better to use than `[text()='Nayan']`
Also, since you are using Selenium it can be Xpath 1.0 only since Selenium not supporting Xpath 2.0 and higher, it supports XPath 1.0 only

Comment: thanks, tried the above two cases but i got  following exception 
                                                                          
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //span[contains(text()='Nayan')] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//span[contains(text()='Nayan')]' is not a valid XPath expression.

Comment: It's not what I wrote. `//span[contains(text(),'Nayan')]`. Not `//span[contains(text()='Nayan')]`. `=` is **not** used with **contains**

Comment: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Nayan')]"));                                    
using this code line iam getting NoSuchElementException @Prophet

Comment: Can you share a link to the page you working on? Maybe you are missing a delay? Maybe page need to be scrolled? iframe? many possible issues

Comment: actually its a private page, even if i share you wont be able to view it sorry hope you got it

Comment: If so I can't see what causes your problem. Try to resolve it yourself. Check if the text is inside the `span` ifself, maybe it is inside some other element, child element etc. Scrolling, adding a pause, switch to iframe.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251472/discussion-between-nayansfosgit-and-prophet).